# Dataframe to RDD piece of code is not working

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I am trying to read each row of dataframe and convert the row data into custom bean class. But the problem here is, the code is not getting executed. To check, I have written multiple print statement but none of the print statement present inside `df.rdd.map{row=>}` executed as if the complete block of code is escaped.

code snippet:

```
 print("data frame:", df.show()). 

 df.rdd.map(row => {
   // Debugging
   println("Debugging")

  if(row.isNullAt(0)) {
    println("null data")
  } else {
    println(row.get(0).toString)
  }

  val employeeJobData = new EmployeeJobData

  if(row.get(0).toString == null || row.get(0).toString.isEmpty){
    employeeJobData.setEmployeeId("NULL_KEY_VALUE")
  } else {
    employeeJobData.setEmployeeId(row.get(0).toString)
  }
  employeeJobDataList.add(employeeJobData)
  } )
```

output of `df.show()`:

```
   |employee_id|employee_name|employee_email|paygroup|level|dept_id|
   +-----------+-------------+--------------+--------+-----+-------+
   |13         |         null|          null|    null| null|   null|
   |14         |         null|          null|    null| null|   null|
   |15         |         null|          null|    null| null|   null|
   |16         |         null|          null|    null| null|   null|
   |17         |         null|          null|    null| null|   null|
   +-----------+-------------+--------------+--------+-----+-------+
```

Comment: Can you post full code here ?

Comment: In Spark, until any collect operation is performed, it won't execute the code.

Comment: ...and if/when it is executed, you should see output printed in executors' logs since `map` will be distributed.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove unnecessary code as below and get `java.util.List[EmployeeJobData]` as below

```
import java.util

object MapToCaseClass {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = Constant.getSparkSess;

    import spark.implicits._

    val df  = List((12,"name","email@email.com","paygroup","level","dept_id")).toDF()
    val employeeList : util.List[EmployeeJobData] = df
      .map(row => {
        val id = if (null == row.getString(0) || "null".equals(row.getString(0)) || row.getString(0).trim.isEmpty) {
          "NULL_KEY_VALUE"
        } else {
          row.getString(0)
        }
        EmployeeJobData(id, row.getString(1), row.getString(2),
          row.getString(3), row.getString(4), row.getString(5))
      })
      .collectAsList
  }

}

case class EmployeeJobData(employee_id: String, employee_name: String,employee_email: String,paygroup: String,
                           level: String,dept_id: String)
```

The above can be improved more by just setting the data type of `employee_id` and  `dept_id` (i.e if its numeric) to `Long` . This `"null".equals` and `.isEmpty()` can be avoided for `employee_id` and code can be further reduced.